# Excel user form

Tags: excel, windows, vba, macos, userform

A userform i've created on windows won't launch on a mac running 2011. The macro to launch the userform is as follows so does this not work for a mac?

```
Sub openform1()

    UserForm1.Show

End Sub
```

Comment: can you post the code from the userform?

Comment: does a mac not load a macro to launch a userform as it does on a windows Sub openform1()

UserForm1.Show

End Sub

Comment: You need to [edit] your question to include enough relevant information to make it answerable. As it stands, this isn't going to work. What's the form doing? Are you getting any specific error? On what instruction, in which procedure? What does "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: On the mac nothing happens when the button i created to launch the userform is pressed. No errors or anything. I created the excel sheet with the userform on Excel 2016 so i don't know if maybe 2011 office for a mac just won't work at all or if a mac launches userforms differently.

Comment: Seems like many people were complaining about this.  Maybe this post (https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_mac/excel-for-mac-2016-looking-for-data-entry-form/6c62f3d5-79dc-4347-a26e-35955b3b37d6) can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to get a simple user form working in Mac Excel 2011: add a user form (called UserForm1 by default) to a project, as well as a module (called Module1 by default) and place on the user form one button (called CommandButton1 by default).  Then put the following code in.  Step through the code and it works fine, naming the button prior to presenting the form.

module code:

```
Dim userform1 As UserForm
Sub openform1()
Set uForm = New userform1
    uForm.Show
End Sub
```

User form code:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    CommandButton1.Caption = "button"
End Sub
```

I do not think of Mac and Windows versions of Excel as being the same program. They do not, in general, mix and match well together.  It's like Apples and ...Windows

Comment: I did end up getting it to work on a mac luckily. Had to change the line of code in the original comment. But thanks